# Execute p4 aliased command result in messed wrong order of lines in output

Tags: perforce

I have the following content inside my `p4aliases.txt`.

```
diff-cl $(target-cl) = diff -dl //...@$(EQ)$(target-cl)
```

Basically it diffs against your files in current workspace toward the target shelved files of changelist.

It is fine. I can execute it. But when I compare the result coming from above aliased command against the direct raw (non-aliased) command as follows

```
p4 diff -dl //...@=<target-cl>
```

the output lines of text from **aliased** command is in wrong order e.g. changes according to a certain file shows up first before a line of file shown, line orders are messed up. This is not the case if you execute with a non-aliased command.

## Example

---

### Expected result

```
==== //depot/common.h#none - x:\mydir\project\src\common.h ====
==== //depot/file.cpp#none - x:\mydir\project\src\file.cpp ====
3a4
> added line 1
==== //depot/file.h#none - x:\mydir\project\src\file.h ====
```

### Actual result

```
3a4
> added line 1
==== //depot/common.h#none - x:\mydir\project\src\common.h ====
==== //depot/file.cpp#none - x:\mydir\project\src\file.cpp ====
==== //depot/file.h#none - x:\mydir\project\src\file.h ====
```

I have `p4` version as of Rev. `P4/NTX64/2021.1/2126753 (2021/05/12).`
Perforce server version (got from `p4 info`) is `Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2017.1/1574018 (2017/10/02)`.

How can I solve this issue?

<strike>Could this be a version too far away between client and server</strike>

**Update**

I have tested p4 client all the way down from 2016-2020 version by downloading old binaries from ftp.perforce.com (in directory perforce). No luck. Output still messed the same. So it's not the problem about version mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the p4 client.  When the client does a diff, it's written by the `ClientUser::Diff()` method, which defaults to writing to stdout (i.e. it does not route the output through `ClientUser::OutputText()`):

https://workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce_software-p4/files/2018-2/client/clientuser.cc#436
https://workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce_software-p4/files/2018-2/client/clientuser.cc#573

Output from commands run as part of an alias go through the `ClientUserStrBuf` subclass, which buffers all of its output.  The file headers, for example, are buffered by `ClientUserStrBuf::OutputInfo()`:

https://workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce_software-p4/files/2018-2/client/clientaliases.cc#1647

There isn't a `ClientUserStrBuf::Diff()` implementation, though, so that diff output  goes straight to stdout while the headers are buffered and printed at the end (presumably after some post-processing) -- hence the diff output showing up first in the console.

The fix I'd make would be to have the base `ClientUser::Diff()` implementation route the output through `OutputText()` when no output file is provided, which seems like the least-surprise behavior; that'd fix the aliases behavior and might even make life a little easier for other client developers who would otherwise hit the same issue.  If you have a support contract with Perforce you can file this as a bug report, or since the client is open source you can take a crack at fixing and building it yourself.  I don't think there's a workaround that doesn't involve modifying the client source code.

Comment: Thank you very much @Samwise ! I looked roughly at the source code (as latest as perforce put on there is 2018), that looks like to be the case. I will take a look carefully and test building this weekend. I'll get back here and give you update afterwards.

Comment: I marked your answer as answer for the approach to truly fix the root problem. I also posted the workaround as well. I'm just half way in pursuing with your suggestion. I was able to build with Jamfile (it needs some patch to make it buildable) but due to time, I didn't manage to fully implement as per your suggestion yet. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Samwise has the correct approach to truly fix the problem at hands although it might take some effort to understand the code, and conduct the fix itself.

At any rate, if we took such approach we won't be able to take benefits of bug fixes and future updates as we will be stuck with 2018-2 version of `p4` as it's the latest as it can be in which we can grab the source.

I would recommend to use WSL then interact with `p4.exe` (yes, a Windows-based binary) for Windows-based project, and `p4` for Linux-based binary. If you didn't use WSL, please find the `.bash_aliases`-like solution as I have below to seamlessly solve aliases `diff` operation.

Put the following code into your `~/.bash_aliases`

```sh
# p4 - fix of aliases diff operation
# platform independent, it will choose a correct binary path to execute properly
p4() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              cmd="p4.exe"    # default is Windows-based

    # get the last argument value, if "-lx" passed in then we know it's linux
    if [[ "${@: -1}" == "-lx" ]]; then
        cmd="/usr/local/bin/p4"
    fi

    if [[ $1 == "diff-cl" ]]; then
        if [ -z "$2" ]; then
            echo "usage: p4 diff-cl <CL>"
            return 1
        fi
        $cmd diff -dl //...@=$2 | diffp4 | less -r
    elif [[ $1 == "diff-cl-fonly" ]]; then
        if [ -z "$2" ]; then
            echo "usage: p4 diff-cl-fonly <CL>"
            return 1
        fi
        $cmd diff -Od -dl -ds //...@=$2 | diffp4 | grep ==== | less -r

    else
        $cmd "$@"
    fi
}
```

then `source ~/.bash_aliases`.

What it does is to allow you to still use `p4` with all of its original commands & arguments normally with exceptions of `diff-cl` (which is the same name of alias I've put into `p4aliases.txt` for Windows or `~/.p4aliases` for Linux). You can safely remove `diff-cl` entry from p4's alias file, or just leave it there. What we have in `~/.bash_aliases` file will intercept whenever such argument matches then execute the raw command, just that we don't have to type long command ourselves.

We can later remove such section in our `~/.bash_aliases` file when upstream `p4` has been fixed.

In `else` section, we just relay the the whole arguments, and it will be performed just as normally done.

**Extra**: `diff-cl-fonly` to list out only files (its depot path, and local workspace path) which have changes.